# Neo4j: Error while Importing db in Graphml format

Tags: neo4j

I am getting the following error while importing `neo4j` graph database in `graphpml` format using `neo4j-shell-tools`...

> XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2542885,95] Message: An
>   invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x8) was found in the element content
>   of the document.

Below is the output from `sed -n '2542884,2542886p' PATH_TO_FILE`

```
<node id="n2479058" labels=":Genre"><data key="labels">:Genre</data><data key="name">myron returns to play ball to find missing player</data><data key="indexed_genre_name">myronreturnstoplayballtofindmissingplayer</data></node>
<node id="n2479059" labels=":Genre"><data key="labels">:Genre</data><data key="name">see others</data><data key="indexed_genre_name">seeothers</data></node>
<node id="n2479060" labels=":Genre"><data key="labels">:Genre</data><data key="name">series: myron bolitar</data><data key="indexed_genre_name">series:myronbolitar</data></node>
```

While `export | grep LANG` returns `declare -x LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` which shows that terminal is supporting UTF-8 characters and hence if there would have been one then it should have been displayed.

Original database is working well. Why is this happening? How to resolve this issue? Any way to by pass the error and import the database..

Comment: Perhaps check that row/col?

Comment: Seems like the GraphML document you're trying to import has problems.  This error doesn't look like it has anything to do with neo4j

Comment: Hi, just executed `sed -n '2542884,2542886p' PATH_TO_FILE` to grep the desired rows, couldn't find any issue. Please check the updated question for the output..

Comment: Unicode: 0x8 is usually a backspace character, which I don't see in the data you've provided.  Do you see anything that in a text editor looks like ^H?

Comment: I ran the above command in console, nothing like ^H in the output. The output is same as above. 
Have I interpreted the row,col correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error resolved.

I was zipping the graphml file for transfer and then was unzipping while importing. I guess the zipping/unzipping process was adding such characters to the graphml file. Transferring the complete file without compression-decompression process didn't throw this error.